# Calculate the curvilinear integral $\int \limits_Г x^2 dy - 2xydx$

Tags: integration

$$I = \int \limits_Г x^2 dy - 2xydx$$ $Г$ - part of $x^4-y^4 = 6x^2y$ from $A(-4\sqrt2, 4)$ to $B(0,0)$
I have tried to use Green formula and got
$$\int \limits_G 4xdxdy$$ when made a substitution $x = r\cos{\phi}$ $y = r\sin{\phi}$ so area transformed $$r = \frac{\cos{\phi}\sin{\phi}}{\sqrt{\cos{2\phi}}}$$
What is the next step, I stuck with limits of $\int d\phi \int 4r\cos{\phi} dr$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization of the arc is wrong :
$$r^4\cos^4\phi-r^4\sin^4\phi=6r^2\cos^2\phi r\sin\phi \iff r=\frac{6\cos^2\phi\sin\phi}{\cos^2\phi}$$
Problem with this is that the angle $\phi$ determining $A$ is not known...

Another way is to parametrize your curve by the ratio $t=\frac yx$ :
$$x^4(1-t^4)=6tx^3\iff x=\frac{6t}{1-t^4},\ y=\frac{6t^2}{1-t^4}$$
There, the parameter of $A$ is $t=-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. You have :
$$dx=6\frac{3t^4-1}{(1-t^4)^2}dt,\ dy=12t\frac{1+t^4}{(1-t^4)^2}dt$$
so
$$x^2\,dy-2xy\,dx = 216t^3\frac{3-t^4}{(1-t^4)^3}dt$$
and your curvilinear integral is
$$\int_\Gamma x^2\,dy-2xy\,dx = 216\int_{-1/\sqrt2}^0 t^3\frac{3-t^4}{(1-t^4)^3}dt$$
It's common practice to use $u=t^4$, $du=4t^3\,dt$, so
$$I=54\int_{1/4}^0 \frac{3-u}{(1-u)^3}du = 108\int_{1/4}^0 \frac{du}{(1-u)^3} + 54\int_{1/4}^0 \frac{du}{(1-u)^2}=54\left[\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right]_{1/4}^0=-60$$
Now don't take all this for granted, I did the math on the corner of a table, there may (euphemism !) be quite a few miscalculations :-) But you see the idea.

Comment: BTW, Green's formula works on a **closed** path.